# Jmeter - How to generate pdf/word report instead of HTML Dashboard?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I'm able to generate Dashboard with jmeter 3.0, however the report generated is in html document, is there any way i can get the report in pdf/word document?

Answer (score -1):

You can easily [save the HTML report to PDF in one click](http://www.labnol.org/software/save-web-page-as-pdf/21153/) using `File -> Print` menu (Chrome Browser and derivatives)

[image: Chrome - Save to PDF]

Other browsers should have similar functionality either out of the box or via plugins.

As an alternative you can consider [BM.Sense Uploader](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/LoadosophiaUploader/) plugin which automatically uploads your results to [BM.Sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/) analysis service. You can export analyzed results in PDF form from there.

Comment: The problem with save as pdf is the graphs are not displayed properly, it is split between two pages, there is no sorting in here i believe. Any solution for this? 

And, BM Sense Uploader, is this plugin for Blazemeter? If not, will this capture the data present in Dashboard as PDF file?

Comment: Dear, it's HTML, I believe it's no rocket science to move graph to the next page by adding few  [<p>](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_paragraphs.asp) blocks in any text editor.