# How to generate PDF Report in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Can any one help me to generate PDF report in JMeter v3.1 as like Loadrunner?

Able to generate Html, jtl and xml reports but unable to generate PDF report.

Thanks in advance

Regards,
Renga.

Comment: (I didn't downvoted) See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38650473/jmeter-how-to-generate-pdf-word-report-instead-of-html-dashboard

Comment: Are you sure you are using version 3.1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your jmeter bin folder and run following command , make sure ur csv file should be correct

```
     jmeter -g C:\vaquarkhan\Software-Testing.csv -o C:\vaquarkhan\Reports
```

then say print and save as pdf report.

Answer (score -1):

You have many path options here.  If manual, then you can print inside of Chrome to generate a PDF output.  If you want an automated toolchain model then I would suggest you consider options to convert HTML or XML to LaTeX and then auto conversion of LaTeX source to PDF or eBook format as appropriate for your use.

I have always thought eBook might be kind of cool because then I could automatically email the results to everyone's Kindle at the end of a test run.